# How to check exact text in list a using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have list a:

```
<div class='label'>
   <a>Menu</a>
   <a>Menu Food</a>
   <a>Menu Drink</a>
   <a>Cheese</a>
 </div>
 <div class="mytext">
   this text need hide.
 </div>
```

How can I check list `a` above has exact text = "Menu".

I used this script but it does not work:

```
 $('.label a').filter(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).text()) == "Menu"){
       $('.mytext').show();
  } 
   else {
     $('.mytext').hide();
     }
});
```

I also cannot use `for loop` and use condition inside.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want for only `Menu` to be showed or `Menu Food`, `Menu Drink` too?

Comment: Yes. Need exact "Menu" in `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjukd5m/2/)**.

You could apply operation for all the matched anchors using return :

```
return $.trim($(this).text()) == "Menu";
```

If you want to show the `div` just if there's an anchor with `Menu` text you could use a flag (`menu_exist` in my example) in the condition then show if `true` :

```
var menu_exist=false;
$('.mytext').hide();

$('.label a').filter(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).text())=="Menu"){
    menu_exist=true;
  }
});

if(menu_exist){
  $('.mytext').show();
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var menu_exist=false;
$('.mytext').hide();

$('.label a').filter(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).text())=="Menu"){
    menu_exist=true;
  }
});

if(menu_exist){
  $('.mytext').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='label'>
   <a>Menu</a>
   <a>Menu Food</a>
   <a>Menu Drink</a>
   <a>Cheese</a>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="mytext">
   this text need hide.
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria. Here you can see what I mean? https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjukd5m/1/

Comment: Do you  want to show the `mytext` div if there's an anchor with exact word `Menu`??

Comment: Yes. and Hide it if no exact "Menu" in list a.

Comment: Ok check my update, you could hide the div by default then show it if there's an anchor with `Menu` : https://jsfiddle.net/Ljjukd5m/2/

Comment: Hi Zakaria. I understand your help. It is useful. Flagged your answer as the best

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.trim($(this).text()) != "Menu"` to select all the elements which is not `Menu` and then use `hide()` on them.

```js
$('.label a').filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text()) != "Menu";
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='label'>
   <a>Menu</a>
   <a>Menu Food</a>
   <a>Menu Drink</a>
   <a>Cheese</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I updated my code. Can you check it again, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled a little bit :-) and used [.filter() function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> The second form of this method allows us to filter elements against a
>   function rather than a selector. For each element, if the function
>   returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in
>   the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded

```js
var list = $('.label a').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Menu"
});


console.log(list.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='label'>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <a>Menu Food</a>
  <a>Menu Drink</a>
  <a>Cheese</a>
  <a>Menu</a>
</div>
```